# populate a switch / case statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to populate a switch/case with options pulled into Javascript via an array variable from a php file.

Is this possible?

```
$.post('file.php'), function (data) {
var res = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(res, function (d, v) {
// Switch Case Statement Populated Here
});
});
```

Added for clarification on why I'm trying to do this:

I'm working on an app and when they take selfies, it calls to the server (php) and returns an array of filters for their photo based on their location. (ie, a frame for Epcot or Magic Kingdom if they're in that location) but its not limited to one frame or filter... so they may have 5 options returned that they could swipe thru til they land on one they want to use for their selfie.

Comment: Hope [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) helps - oh, wait, you want the code to be dynamic - that's unpossible (excluding the evil eval) - perhaps you need to describe what it is you're trying to do, as I think you're doing it wrong

Comment: Instead of an array, you should look into objects. Create a hashmap `valueForSwitch: finalValueOrAction` and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I'm working on an app and when they take selfies, it calls to the server (php) and returns an array of filters for their photo based on their location. (ie, a frame for Epcot or Magic Kingdom if they're in that location) but its not limited to one frame or filter... so they may have 5 options returned that they could swipe thru til they land on one they want to use for their selfie.

Comment: I gave up on the switch statement for this task and ended up just filling a hidden html select box and cycling thru the options there.